# Subscribe to one GraphQL item

Tags: graphql, graphcool, graphql-subscriptions

Using GraphCool for my GraphQL backend, I would like to know how to subscribe to only a single item given the ID. I've been looking at the docs and trying to use filters, but I still can't figure it out. If I wanted to subscribe to all item mutations, I understand that I'd have to do it like so:

```
subscription {
  Photo{
    node {
      id
      title
      url
    }
  }
}
```

How do I listen to an item with a given ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter capabilities known from the Simple API](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/filtering-by-field-xookaexai0/) can be used in the Subscription API as well. You can use the `node` property inside the `filter` object for this. Here's some example for subscription filters in action:

#### Subscribe to created photos

Using `mutation_in`, we can decide whether we want to listen to created, updated or deleted events (or a mix of them):

```
subscription {
  Photo(filter: {
    mutation_in: [CREATED]
  }) {
    node {
      id
      title
      url
    }
  }
}
```

#### Subscribe to created photos and updates to a certain fields of photos

When listening for updates, we can further specify to only listen to updates for specific fields using `updatedFields_contains`, `updatedFields_contains_every` and `updatedFields_contains_some`:

```
subscription {
  # we can only use `updatedFields_x` filters together with `UPATED`
  # so we use OR
  Photo(filter: {
    OR: [{
      mutation_in: [UPDATED]
      updatedFields_contains: "title"
    }, {
      mutation_in: [CREATED]
    }]

  }) {
    previousValues {
      title # contains old title
    }
    node {
      id
      title # contains new title
      url
    }
  }
}
```

#### Subscribe to updates to a certain photo

For all subscription queries, we can further refine the subscription conditions by using `node`. This is the same filter used for `allPhoto`, for example:

```
subscription updatedPhoto($id: ID!) {
  Photo(filter: {
    mutation_in: [UPDATED]
    node: {
      id: $id
    }
  }) {
    previousValues {
      title # contains old title
    }
    node {
      id
      title # contains new title
      url
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. Thank you! :)